# Converting DB2 date calculation to Oracle syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

The sql I that was previously written from someone on another team is this, `(((((CURRENT_DATE) + (-1) DAY) - (DAY(((CURRENT_DATE) + (-1) DAY))-1) DAY)) + (-7) DAY)`. I am not familiar at all with DB2, but I assumed I could convert this using this code, `TO_DATE((TO_DATE(current_date - 1)) - TO_DATE((TO_DATE(current_date - 1)) - 1) - 7)`. I received an error: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month. I have no clue what this calculation was for, but a friend asked me to help him with this problem.

Comment: `to_date(sysdate)` is logically invalid: sys**date** is, as its name implies, a date. What `to_date` should do with date?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is trying calculate one week before the beginning of the month for yesterday.  At least that is my interpretation.

In Oracle, this would be:

```
select trunc(sysdate - interval '1' day, 'MON') - interval '7' day
```

Do test it on a few values to be sure this interpretation is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your interpretation, I am getting with my friend now and seeing if this is what he is trying to achieve. Thank you!